# How to Set up Vue CORS for different domain API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, cors

I' trying to deploy an Vue app which has a separate backend and which will be hosted in different domain. For example:

1. meow.cat.xyz (App)
2. api.meow.cat.xyz (API)

Now after `npm run build` I tried to preview it locally by running `serve -s dist` and the application is severing at localhost:5000. However the problem is it not sending API request at the current end point (which is `localhost:8000` at local and `api.meow.cat.xyz` at server). I tried config CORS as following

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: process.env.VUE_APP_DEV_PORT,
    proxy: process.env.VUE_APP_API_ROOT_PATH,
  },
};
```

**.env.development**

```
VUE_APP_API_ROOT_PATH = 'http://localhost:8000/api'
VUE_APP_DEV_PORT = 3000
```

Note that I'm using axiox. Here is my axios setup.

**API.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

const injectAccessToken = (config) => {
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
  if (accessToken)
    config.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
  return config;
};

const config = {
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_ROOT_PATH,
};

const API = axios.create(config);

API.interceptors.request.use(injectAccessToken);

export default API;
```

and Using it as following

**Login.vue**

```
import API from "@/api/Api";

<script>
  const res= await API.post('login')
</script>
```

This solution is not working yet. Its sending request at `http://localhost:5000`. What's the point ? Note that I'm using axios. thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using axios?

Comment: localhost isn't supported for CORS requests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/why-does-my-http-localhost-cors-origin-not-work

Comment: @DanielBeck that is absolutely not true.

Comment: Yeah .I'm using axios @Deniz

Comment: you can use baseURL instead proxy .

Comment: @tauzN It certainly used to be true, and I'm still seeing [present-day links](https://dev.to/andypotts/avoiding-cors-errors-on-localhost-in-2020-4mfn)  that suggest there are still workarounds needed. But if I'm wrong, great, apologies for passing along outdated information.

Answer (score 1):

**Allow CORS requests from the server**

With the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, you can specify what origins can use your API.

```
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.send({
        api: "your request."
    });
})
```

Comment: I edited my question & added how I'm using axios. Can you please recheck & provide the appropriate way to handle the problem for my case ?

Answer (score -1):

Allow CORS from the app's origin on the server (api).

This has nothing to do with with the client (app)